PowerBI DAX: advice to transform row-iteration into a query
I know that my question isn't very good, but I don't have DAX language knowledge and just try to evaluate is my task feasible or not (without having a monster query as I have a very simple solution now).
I have items that may be in different states, let's name them A, B, C, D. I'm interested to know how much time item was in state B. Each transition from state to state is stored in a table that I have as a source of data:
| Item ID  | timestamp | old state | new state |
| -------- | --------- | --------- | --------- |
| 1        | 10:00     | A         | B         |
| 1        | 11:00     | B         | C         |
| 1        | 11:30     | C         | B         |
| 1        | 12:00     | B         | D         |
| 2        | 05:00     |           | B         |
| 2        | 06:00     | B         | D         |
| 3        | 15:00     | A         | B         |

I would like to have a result like:
| ID | minutes |
| -- | ------- |
| 1  |   90    |
| 2  |   60    |
| 3  |   100 * | 

there are 100 min for ID=3, because it is 16:40 now and it is still in B state (i.e. it should calculate difference from current time if item is still in this state).
You may see that sometimes there might be errors in states or they may be empty.
One more complication - I need to exclude some time periods from time difference - i.e. it is done not by simple subtraction but by separate function that incorporates additional conditions how to exclude some time periods.
Overall number of items is not big - it is several thousands and state transitions are not often. Due to this reason I have really simple script that iterates through all items and calculate required value incrementing it row by row with help of very simple function.
This works fine on a local PC, but I can't publish PowerBI report with such a script embedded (I can't use Personal Mode gateway).
I don't know DAX query language well so have no idea is it feasible to transform my task into it. So I seek advice about 2 questions:

is there a way to transform my interative script into DAX? I.e. how to make right match between 2 different rows in right order?
is there a way to implement a custom function that will do a conditional calculation for two given timestamps (and call this function for every pair of rows)?

